# ASP Classic - To Compare Strings

Tags: string, asp-classic, compare

I have 2 strings:

> string1 = "3122§3121§152KL§256§6598J§65974§3256§6982"
>   string2 =
>   "3256"

I need to check if the exact string2 is inside string1

If I look for "256" the result has to be negative, positive only I look for "3256"

Thanks in advance for all helps

Comment: But 256 _is_ in your original string. so it won't be negative, no matter _which_ method you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InStr()` will not give you an exact match, better to use an `Array`.

```vb
Dim string1: string1 = "3122§3121§152KL§256§6598J§65974§3256§6982"
Dim string2: string2 = "3256"
Dim data: data = Split(string1, "§")
Dim value
Dim is_match: is_match = False

For Each value In data
  If StrComp(value, string2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    'Flag we have a match and exit loop.
    is_match = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr:

```
InStr(start, string_var, string_part, comparetype)
```

Example:

```
string1="3122§3121§152KL§256§6598J§65974§3256§6982"
string2= "3256"
Response.Write InStr(string1,string2)
```

start and comparetype is optional Argument

Comment: Problem with `InStr()` is if you have `§32561§` in your string it will also match. Better to `Split()` into an array using `§` as the delimiter and loop through using a `For Each` checking for `string2` comparison.